# This code works on Xcode but fails in leetcode compiler

Tags: c

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct ListNode *next;
 * };
 */
struct ListNode* removeElements(struct ListNode* head, int val) {

    struct ListNode *beforeNode = head;

    while(beforeNode != NULL){

        if(head == beforeNode && head->val == val){
            struct ListNode* q = head;
            head = q->next;
            beforeNode = head;
            free(q);
        }
        else if(beforeNode->next != NULL && beforeNode->next->val == val){
            struct ListNode *p = beforeNode->next;
            beforeNode = p->next;
            free(p);
        }

       else
           beforeNode = beforeNode->next;

    }

    return head;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problems with this code

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: can you povide a full compilable piece of code hat causes the problem?

Comment: no I did not get a problem but leetcode compiler says you used a memory which has been freed, but I don't thinks so. It may be a problem on their part

Comment: @bake To make sense of that, we'd need enough code to replicate the problem.

Comment: Your code calls `free(p)` but doesn't remove `p` from the list. Probably `beforeNode = p->next;` was supposed to be `beforeNode->next = p->next;`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It is not necessary to make sure that it behaves everywhere the same, as that is the point of your question, but please make it a full program so what we can see the exact context. If necessary provide sample input which demonstrates the problem in the faulty case.

Answer (score 1):

> This code works on Xcode but fails in leetcode compiler

Well, the code is **not working** on any platform.

The test you have done on Xcode must have been incomplete as the code has undefined behavior on any platform.

Look at this simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ListNode
{
  struct ListNode *next;
  int val;
};

void printList(struct ListNode* p)
{
  if (p)
  {
    printf("%p %d", (void*)p, p->val);
    while(p->next)
    {
      printf("->");
      p = p->next;
      printf("%p %d", (void*)p, p->val);
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
}


// Function from question
struct ListNode* removeElements(struct ListNode* head, int val) {

    struct ListNode *beforeNode = head;

    while(beforeNode != NULL){

        if(head == beforeNode && head->val == val){
            struct ListNode* q = head;
            head = q->next;
            beforeNode = head;
            free(q);
        }
        else if(beforeNode->next != NULL && beforeNode->next->val == val){
            struct ListNode *p = beforeNode->next;
            beforeNode = p->next;
            printf("Free val %p %d\n", (void*)p, p->val);
            free(p);
        }

       else
           beforeNode = beforeNode->next;

    }

    return head;
}

int main()
{
  // Initialize a list with three element like: 1->42->1->NULL
  struct ListNode *head = malloc(sizeof *head);
  head->val = 1;
  head->next = malloc(sizeof *head);
  head->next->val = 42;
  head->next->next = malloc(sizeof *head);
  head->next->next->val = 1;
  head->next->next->next = NULL;

  printList(head);

  removeElements(head, 42);

  printList(head);

  return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
0x558311c02260 1->0x558311c02280 42->0x558311c022a0 1
Free val 0x558311c02280 42
0x558311c02260 1->0x558311c02280 42
```

As you can see there are two problems:

- The resulting list is 1->42 but we expected 1->1 In other words - the list is broken.
- The node printed in the last line is the node that we have just freed (i.e. 0x558311c02280). That is undefined behavior.

The problem is this line:

```
beforeNode = p->next;
```

it shall be

```
beforeNode->next = p->next;
```

Output after above change:

```
0x561def3e6260 1->0x561def3e6280 42->0x561def3e62a0 1
Free val 0x561def3e6280 42
0x561def3e6260 1->0x561def3e62a0 1
```

Now the list is correct and there is no use of freed memory.